# Question about one of the pygame methods called get_rect ()

Tags: python, pygame

What is the function of the get_rect () method in the pygame library?

I searched all the sites, but they only used it in the example and did not explain it

Comment: Did you see https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect?

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle ([`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)) with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position.
The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the center of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `center`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments).

e.g.:

```py
image = pygame.image.load('my.png')
rect = image.get_rect(center = (100, 100))
```